# Icons in .NET buttons

Tags: vb.net, icons, controls

I have just started coding my Computing project for my A-Level, and I will admit, I am far more experienced in VB6 than VB.NET (as embarrassing as that is to say).

I get extra marks for making everything presentable, so was wondering if it was possible to add icons into .NET buttons. For example if I have a button to add an entry to the database, I want a nice Web 2.0 looking icon (for which I already have) next to the text on that button.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is. Windows Forms Button has a property called image, which should do what you want. WPF no doubt has something similar. You really should check the [.NET Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.aspx).

Comment: Re WPF: WPF does not have a directly comparable property, but instead the Content property of a WPF Button can be anything you like.  So you would set the Content to be an Image, or a Panel containing both an Image and a TextBlock.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Should get familiar with WPF as soon as possible, but haven't found the time yet...